# Make UITableView Header auto-resize as the user types in cells

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

This UI lets users type in answers in the blanks (TableViewCells) and the header will preview the final answer with blanks filled in to the original question.

For example, the question prompt here should be "The elements that make up water molecules are (_____) and (_____)."

But the UI shows:

[image]

As you see, the header view is truncating the contents. I want the view to resize to fit whatever text is there, even as the user types and the ext gets longer. Here's the TableViewController code for creating the header view:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OPCell") as! WhatTheBlankOriginalPostTableViewCell

    cell.OriginalPostLabel.text = WhatTheBlankUtility.PostText(post: (post?.content.text)!)
    opCell = cell

    let view = UIView()
    view.addSubview(cell)

    let margins = view.layoutMarginsGuide

    cell.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    cell.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    cell.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
    cell.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.bottomAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true

    return view;
}
```

Notice that I wrapped the header view (originally a cell, auto-resizing and worked fine! But whenever it updated the size - I used

```
Tableview.beginUpdates()
Tableview.endUpdates()
```

the whole tableview would jitter if you're too far scrolled down, and the header view would simply disappear if you scrolled too far down for say blank 20. The theory I saw was that because I returned a TableViewCell and not a UITableViewHeaderFooterView, when the tableview no longer thinks the cell is visible it gets destroyed) in a view. This is to solve the problem I mentioned in the parentheses. Forgive my poor organization of thoughts.

I also attempted to make the header view resize by pinning the cell inside to the view boundaries in the code (auto constraints). No luck - no changes to the size of the header view when the user types and the string gets longer.

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but you don't have to create a new view, add the cell inside with constraints and then return this new view. Instead, you can just use `return cell.contentView`

Comment: @Malik YES! It's a great idea! It definitely is cleaner and easier than what I tried, and solved HALF the problem. You see, now the cell starts at a dynamic size with the right height, but as I type, if I call tableview.beginUpdates() tableview.endUpdates() the whole UI jitters - each time the cells "reload" and scrolls down to where I type. If I don't call those, the header no longer grows with my typing... Old problem but 1 step closer!!

Comment: Maybe one thing you can do is to not call begin/end updates on every character input. Instead, put in some logic to check if the current header height is going to be different to the height once the character is processed and only call begin/end update if it is required

Comment: @Malik Thanks for the quick response! I like that idea, except each time I call begin/end update, if I have scrolled down to a cell to type the whole list "reloads" and re-scrolls, which makes the whole thing jump. Doing it once in a while instead of each keystroke would help, but not resolve this issue

Comment: @Malik Actually I'm not sure why but simply returning cell.contentview solved the issue!! Please post it as an answer and i'll mark it as the correct one.

Comment: Glad to be of help. I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new view and add constraints in your `viewForHeaderInSection`, it will result in weird behaviour. For starters, it will add new constraints every time `viewForHeaderInSection` is called. Since, the constraints are not being removed before being added in this method, it will result in repeating constraints and I can only imagine what a nightmare that would be. A simple solution is to just return `cell.contentView` in your `viewForHeaderInSection` method.